# Python short-hand statements with if-else and 'in' judgement

Tags: python

I am going to realize the following functions: 
k is a list, e.g.:

```
k = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,4,7,2,3,4,4,8,9,1,0,2,4]
```

I want to have a list of boolean values if the elements is in a subset of this list, e.g. if element in [2,5,9], return true, else false:

```
p = [False, True, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, True, False]
```

I am only capable of achieving this by standard for loops:

```
p = []
for element in k: 
    if element in [2,5,9]:
        p.append(True)
    else:
        p.append(False)
```

However, what I want is to achieve this with a simple short-hand statements, then I wrote:

```
p2 = [True for i in k if i in [2,5,9] else False]
```

But this gives an error upon 'else':

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    p2 = [True for i in k if i in [2,5,9] else False]
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So how can I correct this?

Answer (score 3):

This is a ternary operator, so you can write it like:

```
[True if i in [2, 5, 9] else False for i in k]
```

or more verbose:

```
[(True if i in [2, 5, 9] else False) for i in k]
```

The ternary operator itself has nothing to do with the list comprehension. You just write an expression before the `for` part in a list comprehension. Here this expression "happens" to be a ternary operator. So there is no confusion/ambiguity here.

But since the `in` operator will return `True` or `False`, you can just write:

```
[i in [2, 5, 9] for i in k]
```